# Run shell command with input redirections from python 2.4?

Tags: python, shell, io-redirection

What I'd like to achieve is the launch of the following shell command:

```
mysql -h hostAddress -u userName -p userPassword 
databaseName < fileName
```

From within a python 2.4 script with something not unlike:

```
cmd = ["mysql", "-h", ip, "-u", mysqlUser, dbName, "<", file]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

This pukes due to the use of the redirect symbol (I believe) - mysql doesn't receive the input file.

I've also tried:

```
subprocess.call(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

no go there ether

Can someone specify the syntax to make a shell call such that I can feed in a file redirection ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should use a Python mysql interface instead of calling external mysql client

Comment: @user131527 The interface would work in this case yes.  I was interested in how to redirect the file from within python anyway and this served as a good example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to feed the file into mysql stdin by yourself. This should do it.

```
import subprocess
...
filename = ...
cmd = ["mysql", "-h", ip, "-u", mysqlUser, dbName]
f = open(filename)
subprocess.call(cmd, stdin=f)
```

Answer (score 5):

The symbol `<` has this meaning (i. e. reading a file to `stdin`) only in shell. In Python you should use either of the following:

1) Read file contents in your process and push it to `stdin` of the child process:

```
fd = open(filename,  'rb')
try:
    subprocess.call(cmd, stdin=fd)
finally:
    fd.close()
```

2) Read file contents via shell (as you mentioned), but redirect `stdin` of your process accordingly:

```
# In file myprocess.py
subprocess.call(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# In shell command line
$ python myprocess.py < filename
```

Comment: It may be related to my config but specifying subprocess.PIPE as stdin just hung.  Reading as a file worked well. Thanks!

Comment: @Sean, Possibly `subprocess.call(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` in "2)" was meant to be `subprocess.call(cmd, stdin=sys.stdin)`?

Answer (score 0):

As Andrey correctly noticed, the `<` redirection operator is interpreted by shell. Hence another possible solution:

```
import os
os.system("mysql -h " + ip + " -u " + mysqlUser + " " + dbName)
```

It works because `os.system` passes its argument to the shell.

Note that I assumed that all used variables come from a trusted source, otherwise you need to validate them in order to prevent arbitrary code execution. Also those variables should not contain whitespace (default `IFS` value) or shell special characters.

Comment: That makes os.system sound far more convenient then subprocess. I was mistaken to think that os.system was being Deprecated. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well, I would prefer subprocess-solution myself, it's superior in a number of ways (e.g. it should be more portable).