# how to test a unix command in Python?

Tags: python

How would I go about testing a unix command like `bc`? For example;

```
philippe$ bc
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
2 + 2
4
3 * 10
30
10 / 5
2
-1
-1
```

I'm familiar with the modules `subprocess` and `os` in python. I also was reading about [ScriptTest](http://pythonpaste.org/scripttest/), but I don't know exactly how to use it ... What I need is to invoke the tool, then pass some operations like `2+2`, get that result ... the remaining it's easy. I was wondering if there's a easier way to do it without too much parsing ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372012/python-run-shell-command-and-emulate-user-input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679974/run-shell-command-with-input-redirections-from-python-2-4

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but this is designed to solve your problem:

http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the [sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh) module, it wraps over unix commands and allows you to call them as if they were functions.  (You can also pass in what you want and retrieve the output)

Comment: I haven't used sh with an interactive command but I'm guessing it can be used via [interactive callbacks](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#interactive-callbacks)

Comment: Also note: you can leverage the stdin and stdout to the command, in your case bc, with the special keywords [_in](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#stdin-processing) and [_out](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#stdin-processing).

Answer (score 1):

For running `bc`, the parsing is pretty easy. You can use `subprocess.PIPE` for communicating with the subprocess:

```
import subprocess as sp

cmd = 'bc'
p = sp.Popen(cmd, stdin = sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE)

# Pass in input, read output
p.stdin.write("2 + 2\n");
result = p.stdout.readline()
print 'Got result: %s'%result

p.stdin.close() # This sends EOF to bc, which closes it.
retval = p.wait()
print '%s finished with return value %i'%(cmd, retval)
```